# Adding to a range of generic lists in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Anyone know of a way to add a value to a range of generic lists in c#?

I'm currently building up a large `List<List<int>>` and the whole process is taking too long and I'm trying to avoid using foreach loops and nested foreach loops in order to shave some time off.

Lets say I had 600 rows in a generic list.  For each of the first 200 rows, I'd like to add a "1".  For the next 200, I'd like to add a "2".  For the next 200, I'd like to add a "3".

The way I'm doing that now, I have to loop through it 600 times and add each one individually, whereas what I'd like to do is loop through it 3 times and add the entries in bulk.

The code I was hoping for would be something like:

```
List<List<int>> idList = GetFullList(); //list contains 600 rows

int[] newItems = {1, 3, 5};
int count = 0;
int amountToAmend = 200;
foreach (int i in newItems)
{
    //List<int> newID = new List<int>();
    //newID.Add(i);
    (idList.GetRange(count, amountToAmend)).Add(i);    
    count += amountToAmend;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but hopefully you can see the kind of thing I'm going for.  In my application I'm currently needing to do tens of thousands of unnecessary loops, when often less than 10 could feasibly do the job if the code exists!

**UPDATE: I'm not sure I've explained this well, so just to clarify, here are the results I'm looking for here**

If I have a list with 6 rows like so:

```
[6,7,8]
[5,6,7]
[6,4,8]
[2,4,7]
[5,1,7]
[9,3,5]
```

i know that I'd like to add a 1 to the first 3 rows and a 2 to the next 3 rows, so they would become:

```
[6,7,8,1]
[5,6,7,1]
[6,4,8,1]
[2,4,7,2]
[5,1,7,2]
[9,3,5,2]
```

This is easy to do with foreach loops and is how I currently do it, but because of the sheer volume of data involved, I'm looking for ways to cut the time taken on specific functions.  I'm not sure if a way exists tbh, but if anyone knows, then it'll be the good people of Stack Overflow :)

Comment: In your sample below your array would look like: `int[] newItems = {1, 2};`. Correct?

Comment: What should happen if there are 7 lists and you have 2 new items? Should only the first 6th lists be modified and the 7th remain unchanged?

Comment: it won't happen - due to the nature it will always be the same amount of rows throughout the loop

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Skip` and `Take` methods from LINQ.

like `idList.Skip(0).Take(200)` it will give you first 200 items from your list, then you may update these items.

For update you may say:

```
int increment=2;
list.Select(intVal=> intVal+increment).ToList();
```

Comment: But is there a way for me to update all the rows that I take in bulk rather than looping through each one, and using .Add()?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
foreach (int i in newItems)
{
    foreach (var row in idList.Skip(count).Take(amountToAmend)) 
    {
        row.Add(i);
    }
    count += amountToAmend;
}
```

Or with a for-loop:

```
foreach (int i in newItems)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < amountToAmend; j++)
    {
        idList[count + j].Add(i);
    }
    count += amountToAmend;
}
```

Comment: hi Botz - thanks for your answer, but it's the nested foreach loops I'm trying to avoid.  I'm able to get the records, but its updating a range all at once that I'm looking to do

Comment: @e-on Those lists have a dynamical length, so there is no way around calling Add() 600 times in total. See my updated answer for another approach with a for-loop. This would effectively iterate over the complete idList only once.

Comment: Yeah this is my question.  I'm currently looping through each one and adding on every row, but the amount of data is very large and this particular function is slowing the application down.  I was looking for a way of adding in bulk rather than nested looping

Comment: @e-on There is no such thing as bulk insertion with lists. Unless you reserve enough space when initially creating the lists, you'll need to call Add() for each item. Also, as i said, with the second approach, you are effectively looping through idList only once.

Comment: Yes I was afraid of that - the second approach is similar to the one I currently use, so it looks like I need to go back to the drawing board.  Thanks for the effort anyway Botz

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin function, although you cannot avoid looping(explicit or implicit) at all since you want to add a new element to **every** list.

You could combine [`List.GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) with `List.ForEach`:

```
var newItems = new[] { 1, 2 };
int numPerGroup = (int)(idList.Count / newItems.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < newItems.Length; i++)
    idList.GetRange(i * numPerGroup, numPerGroup)
          .ForEach(l => l.Add(newItems[i]));
```

Note that above is **not** Linq and would work even in .NET 2.0

---

This is my old approach which was not what you needed:

You can use `Linq` and [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) to redistribute a flat list into nested lists:

```
int amountToAmend = 200;
// create sample data with 600 integers
List<int> flattened = Enumerable.Range(1, 600).ToList();  
// group these 600 numbers into 3 nested lists with each 200 integers
List<List<int>> unflattened = flattened
    .Select((i, index) => new { i, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / amountToAmend)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.i).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Here's the demo: http://ideone.com/LlEe2

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks this looks really interesting.  I'm not sure I'm quite following it in relation to my project though as the Linq is possibly more advanced than I've done before.  So, if I start off with my `List<List<int>>` called `idList`, do I then have to flatten it?

Comment: Maybe i've misuderstood the requirement. I thought that you'd need a way to redistribute a flat list into nested lists. But you have f.e. a list which contains 3 List<int> and you want to add one integer to each nested list? Why don't you use something like this instead: `for (int i = 0; i < newItems.Length; i++)
                idList[i].Add(newItems[i]);` ?

Comment: That's correct - let's say I know for each of the first 200 List<int>'s in my collection, I need to add a "3" to every one. I was just hoping for a way I could add them all at once rather than looping through.  Botz answer above is how I have been doing it up until now, but it takes too long and I'm looking for a way to bulk update.

Comment: I've added the results I'm looking for the the original question in case it wasn't clear

Comment: @e-on: Added another approach, but you cannot avoid looping if that was your intention.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have `amountToAmend` times each item in `newItems` ?
Like :
200 times 1
200 times 3
200 times 5

If so, you can try :

```
int amountToAmend = 200;
List<int> newItems = new List<int>(){ 1, 3, 5 };
<List<int>> idList = new List<List<int>>();
newItems.ForEach(i => idList.Add(new List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(i, amountToAmend))));
```

Comment: Hi Kerrubin, not exactly - for the first 200 rows, I'd like to append "1" to every row.  For the next 200 rows, I'd like to append a "3" to to every row, and for the other 200 rows, I'd like to append a "5".  Does that make sense?

Comment: When you say 'append', it 200 + 1, 200 + 3 and 200 + 5 ? If so, Enumerable.Repeat(**amountToAmend + i**, amountToAmend) would do the trick.

Comment: Hi Kerrubin - I'm not sure I explained the question well, so I've added the results I'm looking for the the original question

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<int>> idList = GetFullList(); //list contains 600 rows  

var iterator = idList.Begin();

int[] newItems = {1, 3, 5};  
int count = 0;  
int amountToAmend = 200;  
foreach (var item in newItems)
{
   iterator = iterator.AddItem(item);
   iterator = iterator.MoveForward(amountToAmend);
}

public struct NestedListIterator<T>
{
  public NestedListIterator(List<List<T>> lists, int listIndex, int itemIndex)
  {
    this.lists = lists;
    this.ListIndex = listIndex;
    this.ItemIndex = itemIndex;
  }
  public readonly int ListIndex;
  public readonly int ItemIndex;
  public readonly List<List<T>> lists;

  public NestedListIterator<T> AddItem(T item)
  {
    var list = lists.ElementAtOrDefault(ListIndex);
    if (list == null || list.Count < ItemIndex)
      return this;//or throw new Exception(...)
    list.Insert(ItemIndex, item);
    return new NestedListIterator<T>(this.lists, this.ListIndex, this.ItemIndex + 1);
  }
  public NestedListIterator<T> MoveForward(List<List<T>> lists, int index)
  {
    //if (index < 0) throw new Exception(..)
    var listIndex = this.ListIndex;
    var itemIndex = this.ItemIndex + index;
    for (; ; )
    {
      var list = lists.ElementAtOrDefault(ListIndex);
      if (list == null)
        return new NestedListIterator<T>(lists, listIndex, itemIndex);//or throw new Exception(...)
      if (itemIndex <= list.Count)
        return new NestedListIterator<T>(lists, listIndex, itemIndex);

      itemIndex -= list.Count;
      listIndex++;
    }
  }
  public static int Compare(NestedListIterator<T> left, NestedListIterator<T> right)
  {
    var cmp = left.ListIndex.CompareTo(right.ListIndex);
    if (cmp != 0)
      return cmp;
    return left.ItemIndex.CompareTo(right.ItemIndex);
  }
  public static bool operator <(NestedListIterator<T> left, NestedListIterator<T> right)
  {
    return Compare(left, right) < 0;
  }
  public static bool operator >(NestedListIterator<T> left, NestedListIterator<T> right)
  {
    return Compare(left, right) > 0;
  }
}
public static class NestedListIteratorExtension
{
  public static NestedListIterator<T> Begin<T>(this List<List<T>> lists)
  {
    return new NestedListIterator<T>(lists, 0, 0);
  }
  public static NestedListIterator<T> End<T>(this List<List<T>> lists)
  {
    return new NestedListIterator<T>(lists, lists.Count, 0);
  }
}
```